# Better path finder than skimage.graph.route_through_array?

Tags: python, image, dijkstra, path-finding, a-star

I'm using this code:

```
import skimage.graph
### give start (y1,x1) and end (y2,x2) and the binary maze image as input
def shortest_path(start,end,binary):
    costs=np.where(binary,1,1000)
    path, cost = skimage.graph.route_through_array(
        costs, start=start, end=end, fully_connected=True)
    return path,cost
```

to find a minimun path from a *start* pixel to an *end* pixel and it works pretty well, but it is to slow for big images.

I wonder if there exists a better implementation of skimage.graph.route_through_array. I think skimage.graph.route_through_array use Dijkstra, i need some implementation with A* with euclidean heuristic.